# Pandas replace values of a column with comparison to another Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to replace in  PF column value by a value in another Dataframe if exists In yellow no correspondance, so leave value as it is):

[image]

and Dataframe with old value comparison and new value:

[image]

I tried to do this but does not work
unicite['CustomerID'] = np.where(unicite['CustomerId'] == Fidclients['CustomerId'],Fidclients['Newvalue'] , unicite['CustomerID'])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, you want to replace the values in `CustomerID` in the table `unicite` with the values in the column `Newvalue` if they exist in the column `CustomerID` within the table `Fidclients`.

I believe you'll have to merge the tables to achieve this.  For example,

```
unicite = pd.DataFrame({'CustomerID': ['a', 'b', 'c']})
print(unicite)

    CustomerID
0   a
1   b
2   c

Fidclients = pd.DataFrame({'CustomerID': ['c', 'f', 'g'], 'Newvalue': ['x', 'y', 'z']})
print(Fidclients)

  CustomerID Newvalue
0          c        x
1          f        y
2          g        z

merged = unicite.merge(Fidclients, on='CustomerID', how='left')
merged.loc[merged.Newvalue.notnull(), 'CustomerID'] = merged.Newvalue
merged.drop('Newvalue', axis=1)

    CustomerID
0   a
1   b
2   x
```